# How can I get "email_verified" (or any user profile data) without always getting the "userinfo" every time I call the endpoints?

Tags: javascript, passport.js, nestjs, auth0

I currently building a REST API using NestJS and I choose Auth0 as a full featured authentication service. Currently, I have been stuck to validate the `email_verified` for certain endpoints.
Let me give you an example for clarity:
The client calls the update user endpoint (e.g.: [POST] .../user) and I would like to make sure that the user's email address has been verified before I call the service from the controller.

This would be easy to do if the `@Request req.user` would contain the `email_verified` since I can create a pipe and check the value of this attribute and throw an exception if it is false. But as Auth0 Bearer token is an access token, it does not contain such information. So what I can do is call the Auth0 getUser endpoint inside the custom validation pipe and get this `email_verified` attribute.

This seems to be a resource-intensive solution so that every endpoint call has an extra API call for the user info.

Here is my pipe:

```
import {
  Injectable,
  PipeTransform,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserManagement } from '@src/user/user.management';

@Injectable()
export class EmailVerifiedPipe implements PipeTransform {
  private readonly userManagement: UserManagement;

  constructor() {
    this.userManagement = new UserManagement();
  }

  async transform(value: any) {
    // TRY TO AVOID THIS SECTION
    const { email_verified } = await this.userManagement.managementClient.getUser({ 
      id: value.sub 
    });
    // SECTION END

    if (email_verified) {
      return value;
    } else {
      throw new HttpException(
        'Bad request: Email not verified',
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any cheaper / good solution to this problem?

Thank you in advance.